# Python error: Mean of empty slice

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load a file in a numpy array and take a value in the column 3 since a condition is found at column 1.

Following there is a sample of my data in .csv format:

```
step,lambda,rate,etotal 
1001,0.0,0.1,-48044.2760681363
2000,0.0,0.1,-48031.1794623084
3000,0.1,0.1,-43205.9046309046
4000,0.2,0.1,-38388.9135212169
5000,0.3,0.1,-33578.2019598638
6000,0.4,0.1,-28770.5652389722
7000,0.5,0.1,-23964.1873174772
8000,0.7,0.1,-14375.4972097742
9000,0.8,0.1,-9572.458083405
10000,0.9,0.1,-4767.3654814475
11000,1,0.1,32.5943003495421
```

My simplified code is:

```
import numpy as np

df = np.genfromtxt('teste.csv', delimiter = ',')

rate = 0.1
idx = np.arange(0, 1+rate, rate)

for i in idx:
    print(df[:,3][df[:,1] == i])
```

I am getting the following output:

```
%run "plot_data.py"
0.0 [-48044.27606814 -48031.17946231]
0.1 [-43205.9046309]
0.2 [-38388.91352122]
0.3 []
0.4 [-28770.56523897]
0.5 [-23964.18731748]
0.6 []
0.7 []
0.8 [-9572.4580834]
0.9 [-4767.36548145]
1.0 [ 32.59430035]
```

One can see that for the values 0.3, 0.6, 0.7 on column 1 Python is returning an empty array. I don't understand why.

If I type in a Python pane, the same command but changing manually i for 0.3 in a Python pane, I find my desired answer as one can note:

```
In [17]: df[:,3][df[:,1] == 0.3]
Out[17]: array([-33578.20195986])
```

What am I not understanding and doing wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `print(df[:,3][np.isclose(df[:,1], i)])`. If you use the comparison operator, there may be floating-point inaccuracies leading to these kinds of errors.

As a separate issue, your test data has no value at all for `lambda = 0.6`. My fix won't fix that, you will need to get a data set which has that value or use another algorithm that guesses that value from the surrounding ones.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know about np.isclose(). The galaxyan's answer is in the right direction too, but your suggestion is more adequate. When I prepared the data, I did not note about the missing value.

Answer (score 0):

you should not compare floating number.

```
for i in np.arange(0,1.1, 0.1):
   print(df[:,3][abs(df[:,1]-i) < 1e-5])
```

output:

```
[-48044.27606814 -48031.17946231]
[-43205.9046309]
[-38388.91352122]
[-33578.20195986]
[-28770.56523897]
[-23964.18731748]
[]
[-14375.49720977]
[-9572.4580834]
[-4767.36548145]
[ 32.59430035]
```